# Possible to have a means to access my saves externally?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, api, saves

Recent changes have converted the Bookmarks section to Saves and made what we have bookmarked private. This is definitely a positive change! However, doing so makes it even more difficult to automatically export one's bookmarks to external services.

As of the 2.3 API, it seems like the `/favorites` endpoint still exists, but are there plans to add a `/saves` one (with the proper authentication, of course)?

If not, would it be possible to have an [IFTTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFTTT#Features) integration or the like?